# Regex to remove multiple white-spaces stops at first space

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the correct regex to remove all white spaces for different formats of strings like:

```
A 41 FR 38 ( should become A41FR38)
DGT 4687 P ( should become DGT4687P)
POL 789 EU ( should become POL789EU )
```

I have tried:

```
[^\s]+

[^\d]+
```

and many others, none seem to work, they would only stop at the first space? For example `POL 789 EU` would become `POL`, and `W 85 EU` would become `W`

https://regex101.com/r/kA1sW4/1

Is this possible?

**- EDIT -**

I have just discovered that the correct different strings would be HTML outputs. Such as :

```
.html">W 45 B 1 A 401 L</a>
```

so I have just tryed: `html">([^<]*)` and it outputs :

> W 45 B 1 A 401 L

(still with spaces) What should I add to remove the spaces?

demo (still with spaces) https://regex101.com/r/kA1sW4/2

Comment: What regex tool/language are you using?

Comment: I 'm not too sure, it is in a software, the documentation is here : https://www.webharvy.com/articles/regex.html

Comment: You have your question tagged `php`. Are you using PHP `preg_replace`? If not, why do you have that tag?

Comment: No it's not php directly. I will update my question because it involved HTML to be able to use the regex

Comment: @Barmar I have edited my question. I have deleted the php tag.

Comment: You can't do calculations in HTML. If a web page needs to do dynamic modifications, it needs to use Javascript.

Comment: No I mean I need the regex to trim some html. I have updated the regex101 link : https://regex101.com/r/kA1sW4/2

Comment: *What should I add to remove the spaces ?* - Use something like `s = s.Replace(" ", "")` in your programming environment.

Answer (score 2):

`([^\s]+)/g`

The `g` flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I think it may help to complete my regex. Please look at edited question.

Comment: You could slice off the `.html">` and the `</a>` and apply the old regex

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler simply use str_replace

```
echo str_replace(' ','','A 41 FR 38');
```

Results in:

```
A41FR38
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I cannot use directly php. I have edited my question.